# C++ - How to check the type of std::any in std::map?

Tags: c++

I have this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::any> map_;
```

When iterating over `map_`, how can I check if `it.second` is, for example:

1. an integer
2. `std::string`
3. an enum

Comment: In the same way as when it is not in a map...

Comment: You can get a [`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) with [`std::any::type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/type), but it's generally best if you already know the type.

Comment: If you know ahead of time that the content is going to be an integer, string, or enum, you'd probably be better off using `std::variant<int, std::string, Foo>` (where Foo is the relevant enum type). This gives you much more direct ways of sorting out which of the three you're dealing with (as well as a pretty easy catch-all in case somebody changes it to allow more types, without updating the type-dependent code to deal with the added types).

Comment: Use [`std::any_cast<T>(&value)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast).

Comment: If every mention of `std::map` is removed from this question, I believe the question remains unchanged.  The map doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to query the type, here are some options.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <any>

using std::cout, std::endl;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::map<int,std::any> map;

    map.insert({1, 1});
    auto iter = map.find(1);
    cout << iter->second.type().name() << endl;

    if (std::any_cast<int>(&(iter->second)))
        cout << "is an integer" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
i
is an integer
```

### Update

For dispatching on the type of a `std::any`, my preference is to use my `any_match` method, which reads more like a case statement instead of a tangle of `if/else` clauses. The following is a rough sketch you can adapt to taste.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <any>

using std::cout, std::endl;

template<class F>
struct ArgType;

template<class T>
struct ArgType<std::function<void(T)>> {
    using type = T;
};

auto any_match(std::any a) {
    throw std::runtime_error("no handler for any_match");
}

template<class T, class... Ts>
auto any_match(std::any a, T&& handler, Ts&&... handlers) {
    using arg_type = typename ArgType<decltype(std::function(handler))>::type;
    if (auto ptr = std::any_cast<arg_type>(&a); ptr)
        return handler(*ptr);
    else
        return any_match(a, std::forward<Ts>(handlers)...);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    std::any a = 1;
    any_match(a,
              [](int) { cout << "int" << endl; },
              [](double) { cout << "double" << endl; }
              );

    a = 1.0;
    any_match(a,
              [](int) { cout << "int" << endl; },
              [](double) { cout << "double" << endl; }
              );


    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
int
double
```

Comment: An important note on `iter->second.type().name()`: The [`std::type_info::name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) method offers absolutely no guarantees of providing useful information. Implementors generally do their best, but generally the more readable the output, the less useful it is for anything other than printing out.

Comment: `std::any_cast<int>(&(iter->second))` looks as the thing I need.

Comment: @Venelin be cautious as it does not scale well. If you can constrain the possible types so that scaling is not an issue, consider `std::variant` as a replacement for `std::any`.